# Inheritance within multiple DbContexts in EF6 Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, modularity

We develop a modularized ASP.NET MVC 5 application (EF6 Code first). Each module has an own DbContext. We have some kind of a "core" module. Some classes from our other modules inherit from core classes. The core must not reference the modules. **Update: The module projects usually reference the core project.**

The database is created automatically. We iterate over all module assemblies and migrate the DbMigrationsConfiguration of each module and the core:

```
Type configurationType = assembly.GetType(assembly.GetName().Name +".Migrations.Configuration");
Object configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(configurationType);
DbMigrator configurationMigrator = new DbMigrator((DbMigrationsConfiguration)configurationInstance);
configurationMigrator.Update();
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
```

//Core class example

```
[Table("Core.ClassA")]
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public HashSet<ClassB> classb { get; set; }
}

[Table("Core.ClassB")]
public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

//Module class example

```
[Table("Module.ClassC")]
public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public string field { get; set; }
}
```

**When we store an instance of Class C within the module context, it fails, because the module context has no reference to ClassA and ClassB.** How can we solve this problem and keep our modularization in separate contexts and modules?

**UPDATE**: We tried to solve the problem with DbContext inheritance. The module DbContext inherits from the core DbContext. That solved the problem at the first glance. Unfortunatelly the automatic migration tries to create all core tables for each module which fails because duplicate tables are not possible. So we tried to exclude all core entities in our module context with

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<ClassA>();
```

That doesn't work too, because the module context loses all references to the core entities (we just wanted to ignore them for the model building and keep all references).
So there is still no solution for our problem.

Comment: Does your module project have a reference to the core project?
We solved a similar problem by putting all our model objects into 1 class library and then have 2 separate MVC projects that used different parts of the data.

Comment: You can't. A module, by definition, is a discrete unit. If you can't factor out a class or classes, then they are core to that module.

Comment: Our modules are similar to plugins, so they can reference the core project. The other way around is not possible (the core must not reference the module/plugin).

Comment: I have a similar question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943043/entity-framework-with-multiple-migrations-and-inheritance-from-base-dbcontexts-w